# I was wondering if a general identity of $\cos^{2m}(x)=\,$[in terms of] $\cos^{2m-1}$ exists?

Tags: sequences-and-series, trigonometry, arithmetic-progressions, trigonometric-series

I was wondering if a general identity of $\cos^{2m}(x)=\,$[in terms of] $\cos^{2m-1}$ exists?

One particular example where $m=1$ is:

$$\cos^2(x)=\frac12(\cos(2x)+1).\tag{1}$$

but can this be generalised to an even power of $\cos^{2m}(x)$ expressed in terms of the next odd power down $\cos^{2m-1}$?

So say for a random example maybe $\cos^{42}(x)$ equals something in  terms of $\cos^{41}$  .

Comment: Even for $m=1$, this is NOT a linear combination of $\cos x$, instead it is being expressed in terms of $\cos 2x$. In general, you can express $\cos^{2m}x$ in terms of linear combinations of cosines of multiples of $x$. For that you may want to look into De-Moivre's theorem.

Comment: @Anurag A okay thank you I've removed that misleading wording what I mean is something that includes $cos$ in one power less like (1).

Comment: Just out of curiosity : is $\color{red}{42}$ random or did you choose it because ??? If it was random, I shall clarify my question.

Comment: @Claude Leibovici I thought it was random but now thinking about it I might have been influenced looking through other posts to see if anybody had asked this or something similar but I can't think where now.

Comment: @onepound. $\color{red}{42}$ is *" The Answer to the Ultimate Question of Life, the Universe, and Everything"*. Have a look at  https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/42_(number) (paragraph : *popular culture*). This is why we use it very often ! Enjoy.

Comment: @Claude Leibovici Ah and there I was thinking it was just a "natural number that follows 41 and precedes 43." I'll apply user zwim's method immediately to it!!!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Let's try it for the cube.

$\cos(x)^3-(a\cos(bx)^2+c)=\frac 14\cos(3x)+\frac 34\cos(x)-\frac a2\cos(2bx)-\frac a2-c$

So to make the most things cancel, set $a=\frac 12,\ b=\frac 32,\ c=-\frac 14$

$$\cos(x)^3-\left(\frac 12\cos(\frac{3x}2)^2-\frac 14\right)=\frac 34\cos(x)$$

And we cannot get rid of the term in $\cos(x)$.

Eventually we can replace it by $\ \frac 32\cos(\frac x2)^2-\frac 34\ $ to have an expression in term of $\sum a_i\cos(b_ix)^2$

$$\cos(x)^3= \frac 12\cos\left(\frac{3x}2\right)^2+\frac 32\cos\left(\frac x2\right)^2-1$$

So this is going to be recursive, and you can find such a combinaison for any degree, I suppose you can try to work out a closed form from Chebychev polynomial, not sure if this is the right course of action though or even if such a lenghty expression is desirable. You wanted a short formula for $\cos^{m+1}$ in term of $\cos^m$ it ends up being not so short...